# Angular2 Http Laravel CSRF Token

Tags: laravel-5, http-headers, angular

Muddling through some Angular2 tutorials and trying to get a post request to work in Laravel 5.2   I have added this meta tag:

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

but I'm not sure how to pass that in the headers section or honestly if that is where it should go.

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '???????' });
```

Update: So I added a function to pull the csrf-token from the meta tag but still have not found a way to get it passed to the Laravel post request.

```
    getToken() {
      let token = document.querySelector('meta[property="csrf-token"]')['content'];
      return token;
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did. Not sure if it is the best way but it worked.

In the main Laravel template I added this meta tag.

```
    <meta property="csrf-token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In the Angular2 whatever.service.ts I added a get token function.

```
getToken() {
  let token = document.querySelector('meta[property="csrf-token"]')['content'];
  return token;
  }
```

In the same service I added this to the post method.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.getToken()});
```

Laravel now accepts the post without the 500 Token Mismatch Error

Please chime in if there is a better solution!!

Answer (score 0):

This should be the same "problem" as with `<title>{{ title() }}</title>`: There's no `component`. This means: Angular won't/can't do any interpolation here. For the `title` tag the angular team provides an injectable `Title` service. For `meta` tags you've got to roll your own solution.

Have a look here: https://wijmo.com/blog/how-to-improve-seo-in-angularjs-applications/

They use `document.querySelector` to access the `meta` element and then `setAttribute` to manipulate its contents.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. The meta tag syntax is Laravel and it generates the token. I updated the question with a function to pull the token to Angular2 so I now have the token in Angular I just don't know how to pass it with the post request back  to Laravel.