# Pass CSRF Token From Angular2 App To The Laravel Server

Tags: angular, laravel-5.3

How we can pass csrf token to the Laravel 5.3 App From Angular2 Post Request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Http Laravel CSRF Token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655752/angular2-http-laravel-csrf-token)

Comment: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">..this is not possible in html because the extension is not blade..it is pure html

Comment: I guess laravel already places that csrf-token meta tag for you. In that case you can skip that step

Comment: How can I get the token on server side so that 500 status code is removed..in angular2 we can modify the header to pass the csrf token..but don't know how to modify that header?

Comment: check here: [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options) or.. use google: "how to add headers angular2"